# Socket exception: Connection reset when unmarshalling with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, serialization, deserialization, unmarshalling

I was able to unmarshal from xml file to a class using FileInputStream to read the xml content, and I'm having a problem using InputStream instead of FileInputStream in the unmarshaling code.

marshal:

```
try {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Message.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        JAXBElement<Message> je = 
            new JAXBElement<Message> (new QName(Message.class.getSimpleName()), Message.class, message);

    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(je, os);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unmarshal:

```
JAXBContext jc = null;
try {       
    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Message.class);            
    Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<Message> je = (JAXBElement<Message>) um.unmarshal(new StreamSource(is), Message.class);
    message = je.getValue();
} catch (JAXBException | FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

Use JAXBIntrospector to get the value.

```
String filepath="C:\\somepath";
FileInputStream xml = new FileInputStream(filepath);
Object result = unmarshaller.unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
Message msg = (Message) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(result);

StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(filepath);
JAXBElement<Message> msgclass = 
unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, Message.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

'Connection reset' has nothing to do with XML, JAXB, unmarshalling, etc. It is usually caused by writing to a connection that had already been closed by the peer. In other words, an application protocol error.